# Stack objects above each other in WatchKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit

How do I place an object (for example a button) above another object (for example a map) in `WatchKit`?

This is the exact thing I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Is it possible? I've noticed other apps, like Instagram, does it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, the only layering is by setting the background image of the group and putting elements inside it.

Reference:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/1095201#1095201

May be Instagram is following the same approach.